Why is react ref such a special feature, and not a regular prop?
I feel like what is tediously done with forwardRef and useImperativeHandle could be done with a regular reference (from useRef()) in the parent, passed as prop to the child, which in turn would populate it inside a useEffect(). Am I wrong?

Given that it's changing in React 19, you can look at exactly what it took to do that in the changelog.

Your approach of passing a ref as a prop and populating it in a useEffect could work in simple cases. But it has some drawbacks:

It's less idiomatic React code, which might confuse other developers.
It doesn't provide the same level of encapsulation and API control. In fact useImperativeHandle allows you to explicitly define the public API of your component. You can expose only the methods you want, rather than the entire DOM node or component instance. This helps in maintaining better encapsulation and a cleaner API.
It might lead to unnecessary re-renders if not implemented carefully.

However you're not entirely wrong I guess.
